# how to make a custom build for tom-select.js?

Tags: gruntjs, tom-select

I can't figure out how to make a custom build for *tom-select.js*. In the *gruntfile.js* I see this:

```js
// build tom-select.custom.js
/* this file is generated by grunt when calling `npm run build -- --plugins=<plugins> */
```

so should I just list the plugins in the command line after `npm run build` command with `--plugins` flag? What is the syntax for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer:

## create /build/js/tom-select.custom.js

npm run build -- --plugins=remove_button,restore_on_backspace